# How to push data which is not hard coded into variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push data into a variable Data[] but all I have is an example of how to do this hard coded:

```
var data = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "Development Life Cycle",
    actualStart: Date.UTC(2018, 01, 02),
    actualEnd: Date.UTC(2018, 06, 15),
    children: [{
            id: "1_1",
            name: "Planning",
            actualStart: Date.UTC(2018, 01, 02),
            actualEnd: Date.UTC(2018, 01, 22),
            connectTo: "1_2",
            connectorType: "finish-start",
            progressValue: "75%"
        },
        // more data goes here
    ]
}];
```

I tried with following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
ganttdata = [];
// DUMMY DATA
id = 10;
RFInum = 'asfd';
start= 1;
LTIOV = 2;
progressValue = 10;

ganttdata.push("{id:"+id, "parent: null", "name:"+RFInum, "actualStart: Date.UTC("+start+")", "actualEnd: Date.UTC("+LTIOV+")", "progressValue:"+progressValue+"%}");
console.log(ganttdata);
```

Anyone know how to write this?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question

Comment: I created a snippet from your code, what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently inserting your data as a string and not as an object.

I recreated your approach and inserted your data as an object into the `ganttdata` array.

[Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

```js
var ganttdata = [];
// DUMMY DATA
var id = 10;
var RFInum = 'asfd';
var start = Date.UTC(2021, 12, 31);
var LTIOV = Date.UTC(2021, 12, 31);
var progressValue = 10;

ganttdata.push({
  id,
  parent: null,
  name: RFInum,
  actualStart: start,
  actualEnd: LTIOV,
  progressValue: `${progressValue}%`,
});

console.log(ganttdata);
```

Or if you want to append some data to an existing object at a specific index:

```js
var data = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'test'
}];

console.log('before:', data);

data[0].extend = 'hello World';
data[0].foo = 'bar';

console.log('after:', data);
```

Comment: I tried your code and its working with one exception. The progressValue doesn't return the percentages, in stead it says: "${progressValue}%"

Comment: have you used the backticks ( ` ) or the regular quotes ( ' )? 
if you dont want to use the backticks you could write: progressValue: progressValue + '%'

Comment: Only issue remaining are the start and end dates, they return NaN. With this code: actualStart: Date.UTC(start), actualEnd: Date.UTC(LTIOV), where start = for example 2022, 12, 31

Comment: i only inserted your start value into the Date.UTC() function.... if you give that variable a value of 1 then it will insert a 1 into that function....

you can change your start value to: var start = Date.UTC(2022, 12, 31); and then in the object: actualStart: start,

Comment: I tried that and found out that there is something not working with the dates. When I have this start= 2022, 12, 31 and use this line of code: test = Date.UTC(start); I get NaN

Comment: @user14010662 I updated my answer. With the date objects created in the variables.

Comment: regarding your last change, when I try this I get an error: Object doesn't support this action

Comment: @user14010662 I removed the new keyword. Now it should work.

Comment: unfortunately still NaN. Only when hard coded like, actualStart: Date.UTC(2022, 01, 01) I get a proper date like this: actualStart1675123200000

Comment: I don't think that's a problem from my solution.
You can try to create a new Question with your new Problem....

Comment: Well your community apparently didn't receive my question very positive (whatever that may be...) so I am not allowed to ask futher questions. It's a real inspiration this site.